# Async JS method not returning value selected from hash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to get the value from a JSON response, and then use it in an axios get request. I'm receiving a garbled string, instead of the token from the userData object. **How do I return the token through the function, and pass it back to the axios string?** The issue seems to revolve around the return function not returning user['access-token']

```
componentDidMount() {
       // console.log("Hello Mounted UserProfile Card!" + this.getToken())

        axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/user_profile/${this.getToken}`)
        .then(response => {
           this.setState({user: response.data});   
           console.log("api response " + response.data)  
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
      }
    
      async getToken(user) {
        try {
          let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
          let data = JSON.parse(userData);
          let user = JSON.parse(data)
          return user["access-token"].toString();
        } catch(error) {
          console.log("Something went wrong", error);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Since you're passing a function instead of a string into your get, you're not going to get a token string. However, something seems a miss as to how you're going about this. I would think an ID to the user would be something you'd pass in the URL and then get it from params, yes?

Comment: You need to invoke the function and pass the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this.getToken` to `axios.get(...)`, where `this.getToken` is a method returning a Promise rather than the actual token.

You can first resolve the `getToken` Promise, then invoke the `axios` GET request.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getToken()
    .then(token => axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/user_profile/${token}`))
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ user: response.data });
      console.log(`API response: ${response.data}`);  
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

async getToken() {
  const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
  const data = JSON.parse(userData);
  const user = JSON.parse(data)
  return user["access-token"].toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like wrong. getToken method is not calling and in this method, you are not using param user. I am not React expert but i think this can be work;

```
   async componentDidMount() {
   // console.log("Hello Mounted UserProfile Card!" + this.getToken())
    try {
       const token = await this.getToken();
       if (token) {
           const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/user_profile/${token}`);
           this.setState({user: response.data});   
           console.log("api response " + response.data)
       } else { throw 'token not found'; }
    } catch (ex) { console.log(ex); }
  }

  async getToken() {
    try {
      let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
      let data = JSON.parse(userData);
      let user = JSON.parse(data)
      return user["access-token"].toString();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```